# Vue :src is not displaying image, but shows in DOM

Tags: laravel, vue.js, tailwind-css, laravel-vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <Header></Header>
    <div class=" flex justify-center items-center" v-if="!item && !product">
        <div class="animate-spin rounded-full h-20 w-20 border-b-2 border-sky-500"></div>
    </div>
    <div v-else>
        <div class="grid md:grid-cols-2 my-5">
                <div>
                    <img class="w-full h-52 md:h-96 md:w-96 mx-auto " :src="product.imagePath" alt="Extol Coffee">
                </div>
                <div class="mr-16 ">
                    <div class="grid grid-cols-4 text-5xl mb-3">
                        <p class="inline col-span-4">{{product.name}} - {{item.quantity_type}}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="grid grid-cols-4 border-b-2 border-gray-300 p-2">
                        <p class="inline col-span-1">Region</p>
                        <p class="inline text-justify col-span-3">{{product.region}}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="grid grid-cols-4 border-b-2 border-gray-300 p-2">
                        <p class="inline col-span-1">Growing Altitude</p>
                        <p class="inline text-justify col-span-3">{{product.growing_altitude}}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="grid grid-cols-4 border-b-2 border-gray-300 p-2">
                        <p class="inline col-span-1">Arabica Variety</p>
                        <p class="inline text-justify col-span-3">{{product.arabica_variety}}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="grid grid-cols-4 border-b-2 border-gray-300 p-2">
                        <p class="inline col-span-1">Milling Process</p>
                        <p class="inline text-justify col-span-3">{{product.milling_process}}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="grid grid-cols-4 border-b-2 border-gray-300 p-2">
                        <p class="inline col-span-1">Aroma</p>
                        <p class="inline text-justify col-span-3">{{product.aroma}}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="grid grid-cols-4 border-b-2 border-gray-300 p-2">
                        <p class="inline col-span-1">Flavor</p>
                        <p class="inline text-justify col-span-3">{{product.flavor}}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="grid grid-cols-4 border-b-2 border-gray-300 p-2">
                        <p class="inline col-span-1">Body</p>
                        <p class="inline text-justify col-span-3">{{product.body}}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="grid grid-cols-4 border-b-2 border-gray-300 p-2">
                        <p class="inline col-span-1">Acidity</p>
                        <p class="inline text-justify col-span-3">{{product.acidity}}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="grid grid-cols-4 mt-4 p-2">
                        <p class="inline col-span-1">Price</p>
                        <p class="inline text-justify col-span-3 text-2xl">${{item.price}}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="p-2 grid grid-cols-4">
                        <p class="inline col-span-1">Quantity</p>
                        <input class="w-32 h-10 rounded-md border-2 col-span-2 bg-white" type="number" name="quantity" id="quantity" v-model="quantity">
                    </div>
                    <div class="p-2">
                        <button class=" block bg-transparent border-sky-500 border-2 rounded-md w-52 h-10 mx-auto" v-on:click="addToCart()">     
                            <span>Add to Cart</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Header from "./Header.vue";
export default {
  name: "ViewItem",
  data(){
      return{
          product:null,
          quantity:0,
      }
  },
  components:{
      Header,
  },
  methods:{
      addToCart(){
          var itemToCart ={
            product: this.product,
            item: this.item,
            quantity: +this.quantity,
          };
          if(itemToCart.quantity>0){
            this.$store.dispatch("addItemToCart",itemToCart).then(r=>{}).catch(e=>console.log(e));
          }
      }
  },
  computed:{
      item(){
        var item = this.$store.getters.getProductQuantities.find(item => item.id == this.$route.params.id);
        this.product= this.$store.getters.getProducts.find(product => product.id == item.product_id); 
        return item;
      },

  }
};
</script>

<style></style>

<template>
  <div>
    <Header></Header>
    <div class=" flex justify-center items-center" v-if="!item && !product">
        <div class="animate-spin rounded-full h-20 w-20 border-b-2 border-sky-500"></div>
    </div>
    <div v-else>
        <div class="grid md:grid-cols-2 my-5">
                <div>
                    <img class="w-full h-52 md:h-96 md:w-96 mx-auto " :src="product.imagePath" alt="Extol Coffee">
                </div>
                <div class="mr-16 ">
                    <div class="grid grid-cols-4 text-5xl mb-3">
                        <p class="inline col-span-4">{{product.name}} - {{item.quantity_type}}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="grid grid-cols-4 border-b-2 border-gray-300 p-2">
                        <p class="inline col-span-1">Region</p>
                        <p class="inline text-justify col-span-3">{{product.region}}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="grid grid-cols-4 border-b-2 border-gray-300 p-2">
                        <p class="inline col-span-1">Growing Altitude</p>
                        <p class="inline text-justify col-span-3">{{product.growing_altitude}}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="grid grid-cols-4 border-b-2 border-gray-300 p-2">
                        <p class="inline col-span-1">Arabica Variety</p>
                        <p class="inline text-justify col-span-3">{{product.arabica_variety}}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="grid grid-cols-4 border-b-2 border-gray-300 p-2">
                        <p class="inline col-span-1">Milling Process</p>
                        <p class="inline text-justify col-span-3">{{product.milling_process}}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="grid grid-cols-4 border-b-2 border-gray-300 p-2">
                        <p class="inline col-span-1">Aroma</p>
                        <p class="inline text-justify col-span-3">{{product.aroma}}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="grid grid-cols-4 border-b-2 border-gray-300 p-2">
                        <p class="inline col-span-1">Flavor</p>
                        <p class="inline text-justify col-span-3">{{product.flavor}}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="grid grid-cols-4 border-b-2 border-gray-300 p-2">
                        <p class="inline col-span-1">Body</p>
                        <p class="inline text-justify col-span-3">{{product.body}}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="grid grid-cols-4 border-b-2 border-gray-300 p-2">
                        <p class="inline col-span-1">Acidity</p>
                        <p class="inline text-justify col-span-3">{{product.acidity}}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="grid grid-cols-4 mt-4 p-2">
                        <p class="inline col-span-1">Price</p>
                        <p class="inline text-justify col-span-3 text-2xl">${{item.price}}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="p-2 grid grid-cols-4">
                        <p class="inline col-span-1">Quantity</p>
                        <input class="w-32 h-10 rounded-md border-2 col-span-2 bg-white" type="number" name="quantity" id="quantity" v-model="quantity">
                    </div>
                    <div class="p-2">
                        <button class=" block bg-transparent border-sky-500 border-2 rounded-md w-52 h-10 mx-auto" v-on:click="addToCart()">     
                            <span>Add to Cart</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Header from "./Header.vue";
export default {
  name: "ViewItem",
  data(){
      return{
          product:null,
          quantity:0,
      }
  },
  components:{
      Header,
  },
  methods:{
      addToCart(){
          var itemToCart ={
            product: this.product,
            item: this.item,
            quantity: +this.quantity,
          };
          if(itemToCart.quantity>0){
            this.$store.dispatch("addItemToCart",itemToCart).then(r=>{}).catch(e=>console.log(e));
          }
      }
  },
  computed:{
      item(){
        var item = this.$store.getters.getProductQuantities.find(item => item.id == this.$route.params.id);
        this.product= this.$store.getters.getProducts.find(product => product.id == item.product_id); 
        return item;
      },

  }
};
</script>

<style></style>

<div>
                    <img class="w-full h-52 md:h-96 md:w-96 mx-auto " :src="product.imagePath" alt="Extol Coffee">
                </div>

<template>
  <div>
    <Header></Header>
    <div class=" flex justify-center items-center" v-if="!item && !product">
        <div class="animate-spin rounded-full h-20 w-20 border-b-2 border-sky-500"></div>
    </div>
    <div v-else>
        <div class="grid md:grid-cols-2 my-5">
                <div>
                    <img class="w-full h-52 md:h-96 md:w-96 mx-auto " :src="product.imagePath" alt="Extol Coffee">
                </div>
                <div class="mr-16 ">
                    <div class="grid grid-cols-4 text-5xl mb-3">
                        <p class="inline col-span-4">{{product.name}} - {{item.quantity_type}}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="grid grid-cols-4 border-b-2 border-gray-300 p-2">
                        <p class="inline col-span-1">Region</p>
                        <p class="inline text-justify col-span-3">{{product.region}}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="grid grid-cols-4 border-b-2 border-gray-300 p-2">
                        <p class="inline col-span-1">Growing Altitude</p>
                        <p class="inline text-justify col-span-3">{{product.growing_altitude}}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="grid grid-cols-4 border-b-2 border-gray-300 p-2">
                        <p class="inline col-span-1">Arabica Variety</p>
                        <p class="inline text-justify col-span-3">{{product.arabica_variety}}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="grid grid-cols-4 border-b-2 border-gray-300 p-2">
                        <p class="inline col-span-1">Milling Process</p>
                        <p class="inline text-justify col-span-3">{{product.milling_process}}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="grid grid-cols-4 border-b-2 border-gray-300 p-2">
                        <p class="inline col-span-1">Aroma</p>
                        <p class="inline text-justify col-span-3">{{product.aroma}}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="grid grid-cols-4 border-b-2 border-gray-300 p-2">
                        <p class="inline col-span-1">Flavor</p>
                        <p class="inline text-justify col-span-3">{{product.flavor}}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="grid grid-cols-4 border-b-2 border-gray-300 p-2">
                        <p class="inline col-span-1">Body</p>
                        <p class="inline text-justify col-span-3">{{product.body}}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="grid grid-cols-4 border-b-2 border-gray-300 p-2">
                        <p class="inline col-span-1">Acidity</p>
                        <p class="inline text-justify col-span-3">{{product.acidity}}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="grid grid-cols-4 mt-4 p-2">
                        <p class="inline col-span-1">Price</p>
                        <p class="inline text-justify col-span-3 text-2xl">${{item.price}}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="p-2 grid grid-cols-4">
                        <p class="inline col-span-1">Quantity</p>
                        <input class="w-32 h-10 rounded-md border-2 col-span-2 bg-white" type="number" name="quantity" id="quantity" v-model="quantity">
                    </div>
                    <div class="p-2">
                        <button class=" block bg-transparent border-sky-500 border-2 rounded-md w-52 h-10 mx-auto" v-on:click="addToCart()">     
                            <span>Add to Cart</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Header from "./Header.vue";
export default {
  name: "ViewItem",
  data(){
      return{
          product:null,
          quantity:0,
      }
  },
  components:{
      Header,
  },
  methods:{
      addToCart(){
          var itemToCart ={
            product: this.product,
            item: this.item,
            quantity: +this.quantity,
          };
          if(itemToCart.quantity>0){
            this.$store.dispatch("addItemToCart",itemToCart).then(r=>{}).catch(e=>console.log(e));
          }
      }
  },
  computed:{
      item(){
        var item = this.$store.getters.getProductQuantities.find(item => item.id == this.$route.params.id);
        this.product= this.$store.getters.getProducts.find(product => product.id == item.product_id); 
        return item;
      },

  }
};
</script>

<style></style>
```

the image exists and is outputted in other components, but not in this component. I fetch the product object from the state using the item.product_id. It fetches the product, and populates the region, growing altitude.....etc and also the image path. In the DOM the image path is filled properly but it shows a "could not load image" error, then shows the alt text "Extol Coffee". The image path works fine as other components use it and display there image.

[image: Image not showing]

to display the image dynamically

Answer (score 0):

Have you check the console and see theres no error request for image ? If all clear then something wrong with this 'w-full h-52 md:h-96 md:w-96 mx-auto' class, i suggest to clear those classes and see the results.